# Millions of Data to be inserted in MySQL database using Spring data JPA

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

Our application is based on Java 8, Spring Data JPA and MySQL. We have two different data source in my application, our task is to fetch millions of data (text stored in a table) from one data source and insert into different data source after some small computation. 
When I tried to iterate through each record and insert into different Database, it is taking a longer time than the expected.

Is there any standard and fastest way of doing this? Do I need to use a stored procedure? if yes, then how would I pass the list of entities in the procedure?

Comment: Be more specific, *"Millions of data"* of what? Images, text, statistics? What kind of data are you fetching?

Comment: @LogicalBranch text stored in a table. Updated the same in question.

Comment: go for multi threading or spring batch process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use JPA. JPAs main use case is: Loading a non-trivial domain model, manipulating it, then flushing it to the database with automatic detection what changed. You don't seem to need that in your usecase.

Use JDBC and batch inserts. [Springs JdbcTemplate will come in handy](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-example/).

Select a batch, manipulate it as desired, insert it into the target.

For tuning the select process consider [value based pagination](https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/art-pagination-offset-vs-value-based-paging/).

For writing consider removing constraints and indexes and creating them after the process.

There might be more MySQL specific options available, but I don't know about those.

You might want to split your work in three thread pools: One for reading, one for writing, one for processing the data.
I'm not sure, but Spring Batch might help with that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load/save entries in batches (100 or 1000 entries in one go).
2. Load and/or save asynchronously.